# SwiftUI how to color a menu button icon in macOS

Tags: macos, swiftui, menu

In macOS i want to color the Image that opens the menu, whatever i do i just get the text colored icon

[image]

```
Menu {
   Button {

   } label: {
      Text("Some item")
   }
} label: {
   Image(systemName: "chevron.down.circle.fill")
      .foregroundColor(.red)
}
.menuStyle(.borderlessButton)
.menuIndicator(.hidden)
.foregroundColor(.blue)
.fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: false)
```

how to color the icon like this

[image]

Comment: See [`.renderingMode(.template)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/image/renderingmode(_:)) and that should allow you to apply the color to the icon. This makes the icon "forget" its original color settings and conform to any modifiers applied - as if it is a custom SF Symbol.

Comment: nope, doesn't work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can replace your `foregroundColor` modifier with a `foregroundStyle` with two colors, to use palette rendering:

```
Menu {
   Button {

   } label: {
      Text("Some item")
   }
} label: {
   Image(systemName: "chevron.down.circle.fill")
      .foregroundStyle(.white, .green)
}
```

Comment: crazy that foregroundColor doesn't work but foregroundStyle does

Comment: @PeterLapisu See my answer below on how to make it work using `foregroundColor`. The reason why `foregroundStyle` with two colors works is that it automatically changes the rendering mode to palette.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @ScottM's answer, you can also use [`.symbolRenderingMode(.palette)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/symbolrenderingmode(_:)) to change the rendering mode to palette.

This will allow you to use both `.foregroundStyle` and `.foregroundColor` (although now deprecated) to change the color of the icon.

In this particular case though, you will still need to apply two colors to get the icon style you want.

```swift
Menu {
   Button {

   } label: {
      Text("Some item")
   }
} label: {
   Image(systemName: "chevron.down.circle.fill")
      .symbolRenderingMode(.palette)
      .foregroundStyle(.white, .green)
}
```